# Incorrect Syntax near ' ' Error, doesn't make sense

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to import `.csv` files into a SQL Server database in a web server. I have about 30000 rows in the table. The delimiter is `;` in the csv file. It inserted 11202 rows but after that it is not inserting and saying;

> Incorrect syntax near 'Farms'. Incorrect syntax near 'Dale'. Incorrect
>   syntax near 'City'. Incorrect syntax near 'Center'. Incorrect syntax
>   near 'Depot'.

These rows are;

```
111203;Greens Farms;12;446;nocity.jpg;NULL
111205;Grosvenor Dale;12;446;nocity.jpg;NULL
111219;Jewett City;12;446;nocity.jpg;NULL
111230;Mansfield Center;12;446;nocity.jpg;NULL
111231;Mansfield Depot;12;446;nocity.jpg;NULL
```

I thought it is about the space (' ') between the city names like `Green Farms` but there are so many cities which have blanks and they were inserted successfully in previous rows. I doesn't make any sense.

Do you have any idea about this situation ?

Comment: Need to see your query, or queries.

Comment: Perhaps you have a quote somewhere in your input and you are doing something nasty like embedding the data in your query as strings. Because of the extra quote suddenly the quotes no longer surround your data but your SQL, and your data gets interpreted as invalid SQL giving you very strange error messages.

Comment: @BoltClock I am not using query, I can not because web server doesnt let it. Just importing csv file with an interface.

Comment: @MarkByers if you mean ' or " I checked the file millions of times and there is no quote.

Comment: importing csv file with an interface.

Comment: What do you mean by "with an interface"? Do you mean a GUI? Or a web form? Is this something you've written yourself? Is it a standard product? Is it something another company made for you and you are just a user of it?

Comment: sorry, yes I mean GUI and it is a standart product. It is SQL Server Web Admin of Godaddy.

Comment: could you mention the line previously to `111203;Greens Farms;12;446;nocity.jpg;NULL` please?

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend dividing your csv into two files. Of course, the first file will contain the 11202 rows that were successfully imported, and the second would include the remaining ~18798.

One would expect that the first file would be imported with no errors.

Then when you import the second file, you might find that you are dealing with a boundary restriction of some sort, if that file also starts bombing after 10 or 11K imports.

Or, you may more quickly be able to spot the problem importing the smaller second file.

If you are still getting exactly the same errors, but only a limited number, then I'd recommend removing the error rows completely and putting them in yet another file.

In this manner, you'll eventually have imported nearly all your data and you'll be left with a manageable subset where again you may be able to more easily spot the problem.

If, after all that, you've got 10 rows that give errors and you can't see any reason why, just use SQL insert statements to put them in your db.

Hopefully this isn't part of some goal to automate a regularly scheduled process!!

I'd be interested to see how this goes for you. Thanks.